# Status bar is disappearing on rotation

Tags: ios, ios8, statusbar

I'm pretty new to iOS, i've done all of Apples tutorial but something is bothering me a lot and I can't seem to find the right key words to solve this problem else I wouldn't ask such a simple question. Everyone else seems to want to hide the status bar but I want mine to remain persistent through all rotates.

Default orientation:

[image]

Any other orientation:

[image]

The status bar is disappearing! Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 - Rotation makes statusBar disappear even in portrait mode after toggling controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176362/ios-8-rotation-makes-statusbar-disappear-even-in-portrait-mode-after-toggling)

Comment: i'll check that out now but I thought he was describing something a little more complex than what I was looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went into info.plist under supporting files, added a new item: 
"View controller-based status bar" and gave it the value YES

I then went to my view controller .m file, and put in there

```
 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
 {
     return NO;
  }
```